# save array in mysql field and search in that field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, dynamic

I have a mysql table looking like this:

```
id
some_field1
some_field2
variable_fields
datetime
...
```

Now I want to store more than 1 value in variable_fields like this:

```
user_id:5;message_id:10
```

The reason why I do not create a separate field for every value I want to store is that these values differ throughout the project. So I am storing different values along the project.
At some time `variable_fields` contains this value:

```
user_id:5;message_id:10
```

And at some other time it contains this value:

```
car_id:56;payment_id:45
```

This wouldn't be a big problem but I want to be able to search in this field. So something like: `variable_fields LIKE '%payment_id:45%'.`

This obviously takes time for mysql.. Is there another way of handling this instead of creating a field for every value? So some kind of dynamic field in mysql?

I happy for every kind of help. Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Freddy

Comment: To me it sounds like you don't want a table with every field but instead a totally new table that holds a "Type" and "ID" with a "Parent ID" which is the ID of the row it relates to in your current table. This way you can easily get the user ID, or car ID, etc by Type and/or by Parent ID `(SELECT FROM newtable WHERE Type='user_id' and ParentID=$ID)`. Storing an 'array' of values is entirely possible but usually considered bad database design as it greatly increases code complexity whilst hindering database performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll add a myisam full-text index or employ any other full-text tools on that column (e.g. sphinx, lucene) those searches you described will work much better, however that isn't advisable.

I would suggest either to divide the dynamic meta data into different tables per case, and keep a type_id in the main table, or keep columns for all options that are set to NULL by default. Really depends if there is a simple division or is this really dynamic and changing over time. In case you're diving the data into several tables, a JOIN according to type_id will give the ability to query by those specific fields values. Be sure to create an index in both tables on the mutual id.